# MSSoap 3.0 Error while creating Virtual Directory with SOAPVDIR.CMD

Tags: soap

I am trying to install a web service (written in FoxPro) onto a newly configured server.
Part of the installation process was to install MSSoap 3.0 which seems to be successful.

The server OS is Microsoft Server 2008 R2 (x64).

I am now trying to create a virtual directoty at the command prompt using the SOAPVDIR.CMD script and I am getting the following error:

```
CMD> SOAPVDIR.CMD CREATE CSLRosterService "C:\ROSTERWS"
CMD> ERROR (0x80070002):
     Soap Toolkit 3 Isapi is not correctly registered.
```

Does anyone know how I can correct this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems a bit petty to edit my post for "punctuation and grammar".

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by:

1. Adding IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 WMI compatibility to IIS7.
2. Editing `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSSOAP\Binaries\_svdir` and 
   changing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSOAP\30\SOAPISAP\isapi`
   to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSOAP\30\SOAPISAP\isapi`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ISAPI module visible in the IIS console under ISAPI Filters?

You might need to run the command under an elevated command prompt if you weren't already.

The SOAP toolkit 3.0 is very old and wasn't even officially supported on Server 2003 if I remember correctly.

Chris.